# Как получить через Telegram API сообщения, которые Бот отправлял в конкретный канал / группу?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, aiogram, бот

Проблематика:
Есть некоторый Бот, который отправляет информационные сообщения в некоторый канал. Помимо бота в этот канал пишут сообщения реальные люди. Сообщения Бота имеют ценность короткий промежуток времени (1-2 дня) после чего они перестают представлять какой то интерес. Задача, раз в N времени бот, должен производить удаление своих собственных сообщений из этого канала, не трогая сообщения иных пользователей.

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно реализовать получение ботом, ранее отправленных им же сообщений втконкретный канал, для последующего удаления?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы Бот, с помощью которого я провожу информироаание сотрудников в Telegram канал, самостоятельно с некоторой периодичностью удалял свои предыдущие сообщения. Допустим, каждое утро в 9:00 Бот получает свои сообщения, которые он отправил вчера и удаляет их. Меня сейчас интересует, как Бот может получать те, сообщения, которые он сам отправлял в прошлом.

Comment: Я бы лично делал так в данной ситуации: При отправке сообщения я бы сохранял айдишники сообщений вместе с датой в какой-то JSON файл (чтобы при сбоях данные сохранились в любом случае). Дальше, я бы с каким-то интервалом (скажем 1 час) проверял бы дату сообщений и если прошло больше N дней, тогда скрипт должен послать запрос на удаление сообщения.

Comment: Только записывая куда-то id сообщения, больше никак. А затем, затем удалять по id. И не забывайте, бот может удалить свое сообщение, которое не старше 48 часов